# Как сделать чтобы Gulp изменял min.css в реальном времени?

Tags: html, css, gulp

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать у меня чтобы при измении style.css сразу изменялся style.min.css в реальном времени при вкл. галпе. Вот скрин [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо всем!

Answer (score 0):

Сделать так, чтобы **Gulp** следил да изменениями **style.css** не сложно - нужно в функцию-вотчер добавить строчку:

```
gulp.watch('app/css/style.css', ['css-libs']);
```

Поставить сюда можно:

[image: код]

НО!!
Это плохая праактика МЕНЯТЬ style.css, если он собирается из .scss - при следующей сборке стилей всё что есть в style.css затрется.